# String crossing diagrams using tikz or braids

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-knots

I was wondering if there is an easy way to create diagrams like the following:
[image]

where a, b, c are colors and strings connect like colors. In the paper I am reading, they don't allow crossings, but I would like to allow crossings between different colors. So something like this would be allowed (two colors red and blue)

[image]

I tried to do this with the braid package, but the problem is that I don't know how to make those semi-circles

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want any special effect at the crossings, such as a cut-out of the lower strand?  Do you want to be able to have strands going over then under so that there isn't a strict drawing order?

Comment: It should be possible to construct a (non unique) polynomial in x and y which crosses zero at specific locations.  Then draw a contour plots for just one level (page 154 of pgfplots),

Comment: @Andrew Stacey, indeed there is no strict drawing order. That would be nice! Thank you.

Comment: @John Kormylo Thanks! I'll have to check it out!

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
        \draw[gray!20] (-5,-5) grid (5,5); % <-- comment this line after seeiing the code
        \draw[red,line width=2pt] (-4,-4)--(-4,4);
        \draw[blue,line width=2pt] (-3,-4)--(-3,4);
        \draw[blue,line width=2] (4,-4) arc (0:180:3);
        \draw[blue,line width=2] (4,4) arc (0:-180:3);
        \draw[red,line width=2pt] (.5,-4)--(.5,4);
        \draw[red,line width=2pt] (1.5,-4)--(1.5,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: If You want colored dots at the end of each line-arc add this line before `\end{tikzpicture}` :

```
\foreach \j in {-4,4}{
            \foreach \i/\c in {-4/red,-3/blue,-2/blue,.5/red,1.5/red,4/blue} 
            \filldraw[\c] (\i,\j) circle(4pt);
        }
```

New output:

[image]

Comment: Interesting! Is it possible to create slanted "through" strings like the first bottom a connecting to the last top a in the first picture? Thanks! This is a great start!

Comment: Circles may take up some space. Choosing three points would be a simpler option or choosing a cubic Bézier curve.

Comment: If I understand the Infimum comment, add this line of code before \end{tikzpicture} (dashed is an option, the cyan color also!):
 
  \draw[cyan,line width=2pt,dashed] (-4,-4)--(4,4);